# In World War Z, do the zombies not bite people with STDs?

Tags: world-war-z-2013

So as we all know in World War Z there is a zombie outbreak. Lots of people turn and what not. But I’m curious about the “ Camouflage” technique used. Which is if somebody appears sick then the zombie won’t bite. So what I’m asking is if a person had hiv/aids would the zombie not attack? With that then a good 70 million people be spared. But based off of my logic and counting all the non-curable STD’s then at least 25% of people in America will live. So wouldn’t that be a perfect solution to humanity surviving?

Comment: Wait, hang on, are you referring to the book or the movie?

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific. I was talking about the movie.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the zombies avoided somebody with a **fatal** disease or infection. Most STD's are not fatal, and the movie does not explain how zombies sense those with fatal illnesses, so any answer here is speculative.

Comment: Yeah, so you've kinda just brought up a huge plot hole in the movie that doesn't have an explanation, unfortunately. Maybe the book might have more answers about this, since it initially created the world and knows it better than the movie.

Comment: “So as we all know in World War Z there is a zombie outbreak” — spoilers! “least 25% of people in America will live... wouldn’t that be a perfect solution to humanity surviving?” Depends on your threshold for “perfect”, I guess.

Comment: From what I have read the film was in development hell for years and take a reasonably well thought out book and uses just the name. I don't think there is much coherence to the movie story.

Comment: I don't recall anything about this in the book. There were "Quislings", people who thought that if they looked and acted like zombies, they would be safe, but it didn't work. Since Q's weren't really zombies, a bite from them wouldn't turn a person, so some people thought they were immune.